# Check if the key value exists in hashmap

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

I have HashMap where key is bird specie and value is number of perceptions. Here is my code:

```
public class Program {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, Integer> species = new HashMap<>();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    species.put("hawk (buteo jamaicensis)", 2);
    species.put("eagle (aquila chrysaetos)", 4);
    species.put("sparrow (passeridae)", 5);

    System.out.println("What specie?"); //output "chicken"
    String specie = reader.nextLine();

    for (HashMap.Entry<String, Integer> entry: species.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().contains(specie)) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue()+" perceptions");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not in database!");
        }
    } 
}
```

}

How I can check if the specie exists in hashmap? For example if the specie output is "chicken" and it's not in database, then the program should print "Not in database!". Now the output is:

```
Not in database!
Not in database!
Not in database!
```

And my goal output is:

```
Not in database!
```

Comment: Why are you looping over all the entries of the HashMap, when you could just call `containsKey`?

Comment: why not just call map.get and test if the returning value exists

Comment: Where do you see "chicken" here : `species.put("hawk (buteo jamaicensis)", 2);
    species.put("eagle (aquila chrysaetos)", 4);
    species.put("sparrow (passeridae)", 5);` ?

Comment: @davidxxx That's why the expected output is "Not in database!"

Comment: Many people seem to be missing the fact that OP is (seemingly intentionally) checking whether each String key contains the input String, not just checking whether they're equal.

Comment: @Dukeling  Anyway it makes no sense. If the OP adds three entries in the map, we expect to have 3 println in any case. I vote to close.

Comment: @Dukeling what is the point to check if substring key is present in a map and answer with that is present? I think you are missing the real point.

Comment: Note: "species" is the singular of "species".

Comment: You ought to reconsider: are accesses to your hash map bound to use the full name (common English plus Latin), or just the common name, or maybe just the Latin name? You might want to map both, the English name as well as the Latin name to a Bird object where you keep both terms (and maybe more) as fields.

Comment: Note that even Latin names aren't what your example demonstrates. A sparrow could be a "passer domesticus" or a "passer montanus" - so what should your lookup-procedure be able to do?

Answer (score 2):

Use a boolean flag for this:

```
boolean found = false;
for (HashMap.Entry<String, Integer> entry: species.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().contains(specie)) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue()+" perceptions");
            found = true;
        }
} //Loop ends
if (!found) {
        System.out.println("Not in database!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Java 8 Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) for this: (although I'd probably just recommend a for-loop instead)

```
Optional<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> match = 
      species.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getKey().contains(specie)).findAny();
if (match.isPresent())
   System.out.println(match.get().getKey()+" : "+match.get().getValue()+" perceptions");
else
   System.out.println("Not in database!");
```

`.stream` turns the entry set into a stream.
`.filter` removes all but the element we're looking for.
`.findAny` returns an element if one exists.

---

Although, if you're looping through a Map to find what you're looking for, that sort of undermines the purpose of a Map and you might want to opt for a List of some custom class, splitting the String into 2 and then having the key be the common English name (as laune recommended in the comments) or using a more complex data structure that allows for efficient substring lookup like a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree).

Answer (score 0):

I think streams is an overkill for that.

```
if(species.containsKey(selectedSpecie)) {
   return species.get(selectedSpecie);
} else {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Not in database!");
}
```